# Why is Kudu node version not updating after setting is applied?

Tags: azure, npm, npm-install, continuous-deployment, kudu

I've been trying to deploy an Angular Application to Azure App Service, the deploy fails and it gives the following log:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment.
  Restore completed in 862 ms for D:\home\site\repository\src\Bearbersys.ui\Bearbersys.ui.csproj.
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20+g88f5fadfbe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 418.94 ms for D:\home\site\repository\src\Bearbersys.ui\Bearbersys.ui.csproj.
  Bearbersys.ui -> D:\home\site\repository\src\Bearbersys.ui\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\Bearbersys.ui.dll
  Bearbersys.ui -> D:\home\site\repository\src\Bearbersys.ui\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\Bearbersys.ui.Views.dll
EXEC : npm ERR! error : Method Not Allowed [D:\home\site\repository\src\Bearbersys.ui\Bearbersys.ui.csproj]
  npm ERR!     at errorResponse (D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\1.4.28\node_modules\npm\lib\cache\add-named.js:260:10)
  npm ERR!     at D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\1.4.28\node_modules\npm\lib\cache\add-named.js:203:12
  npm ERR!     at saved (D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\1.4.28\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:167:7)
  npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
  npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
  npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
  npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

  npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
  npm ERR! command "node" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\1.4.28\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
  npm ERR! cwd D:\home\site\repository\src\Bearbersys.ui\ClientApp
  npm ERR! node -v v0.10.40
  npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
  npm ERR! code E405
D:\home\site\repository\src\Bearbersys.ui\Bearbersys.ui.csproj(39,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm install" exited with code 1.
Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet publish "D:\home\site\repository\src\Bearbersys.ui\Bearbersys.ui.csproj" --output "D:\local\Temp\8d6e13963485ed1" --configuration Release
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\81.10329.3844\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

After some research I've found that this has something to do with the node package in my App Service, thus I've tried to add the following Application Setting to it:

```
[
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
    "value": "10.15.3",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
]
```

`10.15.3` is the current node version and the same version installed in my computer when I created the Angular App, even though the setting is succefully applied the error persists after redeploying. I've also noticed that the node version showed by the log hasn't changed.

```
  npm ERR! node -v v0.10.40
  npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
```

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: Found the problem, version 10.15.3 is not available at Azure, I tried an older version and it worked just fine.

Comment: Try using 10.15.2 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nodejs release schedule, please refer to: https://github.com/nodejs/Release

Find current nodejs versions available in Azure Windows WebApps, navigate to this link:

```
https://<yourwebappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/diagnostics/runtime
```

You can only use the versions available in this list.

New versions are added regularly, so please check for newer versions using the `/api/diagnostics/runtime` url above.

[image]